# rails3 cancan load_resource for custom actions

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cancan, custom-action

I am using cancan 1.6.8 in my application.

I have to create a Cart in my custom method. So I have added custom actions in my routes.rb. Example:

```
resources :carts
   collection do
     get "new_cart"
     post "create_cart"
   end
end
```

How to initialize new object(`@cart = Cart.new`) using **load_resource** for my custom methods(new_cart, create_cart) ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Specify `:new` which actions are new resource actions in addition to `:new` and `:create`.
Pass an action name into here if you would like to build a new resource instead of fetch one.

Example:

```
load_resource :new => [:new_cart, :create_cart]
```

Reference http://rdoc.info/github/ryanb/cancan/master/CanCan/ControllerAdditions/ClassMethods:load_resource